# Neo4j: weighted relationships, how to reflect important relationships in query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data in which some relationships are much important than others and weighted to indicate it.
For example, I have the graph like this:

```
  (city_a:City)-[:has{weight:10}]->(casino:Event)
  (city_a:City)-[:has{weight:1}]->(restaurant:Event)
  (city_a:City)-[:has{weight:30}]->(university:Event)    
  (city_a:City)-[:has{weight:25}]->(library:Event) 
   ......
  (city_b:City)-[:has{weight:2}]->(casino:Event)
  (city_b:City)-[:has{weight:2}]->(restaurant:Event)
  (city_b:City)-[:has{weight:5}]->(university:Event)    
  (city_b:City)-[:has{weight:10}]->(library:Event) 
   ......
```

and I have an input as following

```
  Input: {casino, restaurant, university}
```

and I should output

```
  Output: city_a
```

as an answer since it has most relationships weighted more than other cities.

(Maybe my graph model is not the right one, but I could not think of something also. advices are very welcomed).

So, how to write cypher query for this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming the cities after the break should be "city_b" instead of "city_a"? Also, please make sure you're correctly using labels and properties, the sample that you added, if used as-is, only has variables, which are lost after the query ends, so these would all be blank nodes connected to each other.

Comment: Also, is it required that the city has all items specified by the input, or can it only have a subset, meaning an output might be a city with only a casino if it's weight is extremely high?

Comment: @InverseFalcon. thank you for pointing out my mistakes, i fixed. It is required to output a list of cities order by from top city, which has has more items specified as possible, to low city which has few items with low weights.

Comment: @InverseFalcon . I am not sure if this is the right way to build graph for such requirement.

Comment: You may want to read through the developers documentation again. Your fixes add labels, which is a start, but your "city_a", "city_b", "casino", etc are still variables, and will not be saved to the database. You need to have these as properties of your nodes. Variables are only so you can work with the some elements or values within a query, they don't persist after a query ends.

Comment: So if the you have "city_a" with the highest total weight, but only 1 of the 3 inputs, and "city_b" with the second highest weight, but all 3 inputs, which should be ordered first?

Comment: @InverseFalcon The city with all 3 input should be list at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example graph based on your description, with 'city_c' thrown in to cover the case of a city with fewer than the desired input events:

```
merge (city_a:City{name:'city_a'})
merge (city_b:City{name:'city_b'})
merge (city_c:City{name:'city_c'})

merge (casino:Event{name:'casino'})
merge (restaurant:Event{name:'restaurant'})
merge (university:Event{name:'university'})
merge (library:Event{name:'library'})

merge (city_a)-[:has{weight:10}]->(casino)
merge (city_a)-[:has{weight:1}]->(restaurant)
merge (city_a)-[:has{weight:30}]->(university)    
merge (city_a)-[:has{weight:25}]->(library) 

merge (city_b)-[:has{weight:2}]->(casino)
merge (city_b)-[:has{weight:2}]->(restaurant)
merge (city_b)-[:has{weight:5}]->(university)    
merge (city_b)-[:has{weight:10}]->(library) 

merge (city_c)-[:has{weight:100}]->(university)
```

We'll also want an index on :Event(name) for quick lookups by your input strings (you'll probably also want an index on :City(name), though this won't be needed or used with this particular query)

```
create index on :Event(name)
```

From this we can create the query to match from input events to cities with those events and order by the number of matching events per city and the sum of the ratings.

Instead of the `with ... as input` you'd want to parameterize your query.

```
with ['casino', 'restaurant', 'university'] as input
match (e:Event)<-[r:has]-(city:City)
where e.name in input
with city, count(r) as eventCount, sum(r.weight) as weightSum
return city, eventCount, weightSum
order by eventCount desc, weightSum desc
limit 1
```